# Storing Groups of Strings in Vectors

Tags: c++

The program that im trying to do is to read in groups of strings into vectors but separated by a '\n'.

Example input:

```
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA  // store all A in a vector

BB
BB    // store all B in another vector
```

I do not need to have both vectors at the same time.
I have tried the following but have not been able to store it correctly.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> board;
    string input;
    while(getline(cin, input, '\n')) 
        board.push_back(input);
    for (int i=0; i<board.size(); i++){
        printf("%s\n", board[i]);
        printf("----------\n");
    }  
}
```

Comment: How will you mark the end of input?

Comment: What's the expected output and how does the program know when to store a line in a different vector?

Comment: @SaileshD The ouput is to print the contents of the vectors and when you hit an empty line it should be a different vector

Comment: @P.W There is no specific end of input its just the example i gave

Comment: Read until you get an empty line, process and clear the vector, repeat. When getline returns false you've reached the end of the input, so if your vector is not empty, process it one last time.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer? @RetiredNinja